# Seeking for a formula or an expression to generate non-repeatative random number ..

Tags: sequences-and-series, tag-removed

With my personal interest and hobby I started this ..
Given a sequence of numbers 1,2,3 .... N 
where N is the highest among the sequence and length of the sequence as well ..
I tried my best to bring up a relationship where y=f(n) .. so that .. y (equal or not-equal to n) is an unique value for each value of n bounded within N,

for example:

for the sequence:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Corresponding sequence would be ..
3, 2, 5, 1, 4 (or Assume some other random sequence of same numbers) ..
 where 3=f(1), 2=f(2), etc ..
 The function f(n) must effectively work for all values of N .. ie we must be able to generate the random sequence of any value of N.

Initially I tried with  `y = (n * 9) % N,  y = (n * 7) % N and y = (n * 3) % N`
But they work only if the number is divisible by 10 and the max number if not divisible by 3, 7 and 9 ..

Is it possible to generalize the formula .. ? Please help me in deriving the same ..

Comment: I can't figure out what your question is asking; it appears to be a programming question, not a math one; it is "repetitive", not "repeatative"; and I think this is not of interest to professional mathematicians. Perhaps StackOverflow or one of the forums listed in http://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatnot can help.

Comment: Nah ! this is not a programming related question.. its pure maths .. and that is what I have written there .. By the way .. Its quite easy with the programming I know ..

Comment: One would think that a question which can be answered by a citation to _The Art of Computer Programming_ would be well within the purview of Stack Overflow.  Did you trying asking it over there?

Comment: I don't need a program .. It must be a kind of PICK .. like in the above example, If I want to pick the first number it should map to the number 3 .. which is because of the function or formula f(n) .. I need to create such a kind of formula which is generalized for all the values of N .. thanx for the response .. :-)

Comment: Did you follow the link in Steve Huntsman's answer below?  It directs you to _The Art of Computer Programming_, in which a certain algorithm is described to explicitly and efficiently generate random permutations.  Doesn't this answer your question?  If not, it is totally unclear to me what you're asking for.  

Comment: Not exactly its again helpful for programmers .. I need to map that in an excel sheet .. I am just trying to avoid programming .. In case of mapping we are not allowed to use conditional statements or loops .. I am trying many things in parallel, I will sure write it if I get something working in my favor .. thanx for the concern and interaction .. For the time-being I will upvote and accept Steve Huntsman .. which seems a somewhat relevant ..

Comment: It seems that you have a very definite meaning for the word "mapping" which doesn't correspond to what I would normally allow.  I suspect that you have a finite list of operations that you wish to use to construct your function.  It might help if you listed those, since in building a function (or "formula") I would normally allow conditionals and loops (which can be done in OpenOffice spreadsheets - don't know about Excel, though).

Comment: I thought a map was a left-unique, left-total relation.

Comment: I've closed the question: we can interpret it as a real question if we want to, but the onus is on the poster to ask a real question! As asked, it's essentially nonsense.

Comment: This was far from nonsense. What was misleading was that the questioner's name includes "programmer" so people kept giving programming references. 

Comment: This wasn't an off-topic or program related question, I was working on Excel file and needed a mathematical support, so asked that in this forum .. I don't know what was the strong reason behind closing the question .. (yes)I am a programmer and my account is there in stackoverflow .. http://stackoverflow.com/users/215234/infant-programmer .. But that has nothing to deal with my question and closing the question doesn't matter by the way .. I have got my answer and I have accepted it too .. thank you mathoverflow all the ways ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we hear random permutations, we bring in our intuition about permutations, and try to give a method which could generate a complicated permutation. Thus, I think we didn't pay enough attention to your examples like n*3 mod N, which for most situations would not be an acceptable way of generating random numbers. The only problem is what to do if N is divisible by 3. As far as I can tell, divisibility by 10 is irrelevant, so I'm not sure why you mentioned it.

You say you don't want to write a program, just a simple formula in Excel. This is reasonable, and even something which makes sense mathematically: There are a few operations available in Excel formulas such as addition, exponentiation, factorial, conditional evaluation based on whether a statement is true or false (characteristic functions), etc. Can one create a formula with fixed complexity which takes in n and N, and which is a permutation of {1,...,N] for a fixed N? Trivially returning n works, but can one produce a permutation other than (+-n+k mod N)+1?

I suggest creating a formula which is equivalent to the following:

If N is not divisible by 71, return (71*n mod N) + 1.
Otherwise N is divisible by 71. Permute the last digit base 71: return a + (3*b mod 71) +1
where n-1 = a + b and a is divisible by 71 and $0 \le b \lt 93$, i.e.,
b = n-1 mod 71.
a = n-1 - (n-1 mod 71).

IF(MOD(N,71)!=0,n-(MOD(n-1,71)) + MOD(3*(MOD(n-1,71),71),MOD(71*n,N)+1).

(Debugging left to the reader.)

This would be lousy as a random permutation, but it may be acceptable for some purposes.

A better random permutation might be based on f(n), where f reverses the lowest binary digits of n if n is at most than the greatest power of 2 less than N, and does nothing if n is greater. Try f(N+1-f(n)). This can be done using the DEC2BIN and StrReverse functions, but you need a little Excel expertise to use those.

Once you have a few ways to generate random permutations, you can compose them, and even using unsatisfactory random permutations like adding floor(sqrt(N)) can improve the appearance of the resulting permutation.

Comment: Thanks for the support sir, I will refer this as the answer and follow-on .. 

Comment: While I agree with your interpretation of the question, I am very nervous about your answer. In particular, I don't like the idea that composing several poor sources of randomness is a good way to make a random number generator. As Donald Knuth says, "random numbers should not be generated with a method chosen at random". See the introduction to Chapter 3 in The Art of Computer Programming, Volume II, for an example of how this can fail.

Comment: Of course, the previous comment assumes that we need a high quality source of randomness, such as would be used in cryptography or for a gambling website. If we just something that looks random to a casual observer, your solution is probably fine.

Answer (score 4):

You want a random permutation. See the [Knuth shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle).

Comment: Thanx for the useful link .. Please add-up something if you are familiar with, which helps in mapping rather than programming .. Mapping I mean to say is something where it is allowed to write one formula (no conditions and loops) common for all numbers ..

Comment: The only closed form for general n is the description given.  The function is not smooth or continuous, and I see no reason to believe that a closed-form expression exists for any n.

Comment: Yup I agree with you @Harry Gindi

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used EXCEL in forever, but here is how I would implement the Knuth shuffle in what I would think of as a generic spreadsheet. I want two 1-dimensional arrays, which I will call $x[i]$ and $y[i]$, and one 2-dimensional array $z[i,j]$. Think of three worksheets.

$x[i]$ is a random variable with value chosen from $\{ 1,2, \ldots, n-i+1 \}$.

$z[1,j]=j$.

For $i>1$, we have $z[i,j] = \mathrm{IF}(j \geq x[i],\  z[i-1, j],\  z[i-1,j+1]]$. (Here $\mathrm{IF}(P,a,b)$ returns $a$ if $P$ is true and $b$ otherwise.)

And $y[i]$, our output, is $z[i][x[i]]$.

---

An example: if y[i] is

$$\begin{matrix} 4 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 \end{matrix}$$

then $z$ is

$$\begin{matrix} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 3 \\ 
2 & 2 & 3 & 5 &   \\
3 & 3 & 5 &   &   \\
4 & 5 &   &   &   \\
5 &   &   &   &   \\
\end{matrix}$$

and $y$ is

$$\begin{matrix} 4 & 2 & 1 & 5 & 3 \end{matrix}.$$

---

It occurs to me that some of the spreadsheet software I worked with didn't allow an expression like $y[i][x[i]]$, but only allowed me to address a cell by its location plus a constant offset. Here is a hack to get around that: define $z[i] = \sum_{j} y[i,j] - \sum_j y[i+1,j]$. Any spreadsheet should let you total up columns.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you are looking for. Am I required to fit my formula in O(1) cells, independent of n? If so, things become much harder and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: That's really great of you sir .. thanx for help and support .. :-)

Comment: Well said @david .. and I am glad that you appreciated my questioning .. The answer has not been actually accepted (I just accepted Douglas's answer because he said ITS POSSIBLE) .. and I am still doing research on the need ..

Comment: In case of programming we are facilitated with RAM and processor resolving algorithm with powerful loops and stuff .. But as you know thats not the case with mapping .. where we are left with only a (essentially complicated,) formula which picks the numbers in jumbled fashion (not-repeatedly) .. 

Comment: Best analogy would be the most perfect Playlist shuffling algorithm (which instantly picks up a track in the list, but doesn't repeat) .. The only way left is to convert that shuffling algorithm into a complicated formula .. ;-) I know its certainly hardly possible stuff .. well. by the way, I don't forget to thank your support and interest ..